# How to simplify if statement in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic

How can I simplify this ternary expression in React?

```
{dataIndex ? (
    <>{!obj[i] ? 'N/A' : <>{obj[i][dataIndex] ? obj[i][dataIndex] : 'N/A'}</>}</>
) : (
    <>{!obj[i] ? 'N/A' : obj[i]}</>
)}
```

Apparently its too complicated and i need to simplify it. Any advice? Maybe without the fragments too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use optional chaining and `||` instead of the conditional operator:

```
{dataIndex ? (
  obj[i]?.[dataIndex] || 'N/A'
) : (
  obj[i] || 'N/A'
)}
```

Note that there's no need to surround the resulting expressions in `<>` fragments - using the expressions themselves alone is sufficient.

If looking up the `dataIndex` property is OK even if `dataIndex` is falsey - which is very likely OK unless you have really weird getters - this could simplify to

```
{ obj[i]?.[dataIndex] || obj[i] || 'N/A' }
```